# DM EMI filter components calculations

Tags: noise, emc, passive-filter, emi-filtering, common-mode

I'm attempting to design a passive DMEMI filter according to the paper titled "[guideline for a simplified differential mode EMI filter design](https://www.pes-publications.ee.ethz.ch/uploads/tx_ethpublications/Abstract_IEEE_Transactions_Raggl.pdf)". Two formulas are presented in this paper to calculate C and L of DMEMI filter.

[image]

But the values I've calculated by these formulas are not compatible with the information presented in tables II and III.

[image]

would you please tell me what am i doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a fairly-complicated calculation and it makes sense of course for these cascaded \$LC\$ filters. Did you try to simulate the ac response of a two-stage filter featuring the recommended values and verify that with a 150-kHz you obtain the expected 65-dB attenuation? It would be fairly simple with a SPICE .AC simulation. Does the paper specify which \$k\$ values were adopted for caps and inductors? By the way, I like to include units in Mathcad so that equation homogeneity is always tested in the end and ensures a correct formula.

Comment: @VerbalKint, k values are also provided by the paper (look at the latest picture I've attached). yes. I agree with you. it would be better if I could mention the units also but the problem was that I couldn't find the dBuV unit for attenuation so I didn't insert any unit. do you know how to apply dBuV?

Comment: dBµV is just a way to log-compress the value in volt and you can easily return to the original value in volt: 0 dBµV = 1 µV and 60 dBµV = 1 mV for instance.